# I am not seeing any records in my browser when changing to Iron Router in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have been following the 'Discover Meteor' book and I have just started getting my around routing.  In the book I add a Yield to my layout:

```
<div id="main" class="row-fluid">
    {{> yield}}
</div>
```

Next I set up my router.js so that it points to my Template:

```
Router. configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router. map(function() {
    this. route('postsList' , {path: '/' });
});
```

My template is pretty simple:

```
<template name="postsList">
    <div class="posts">
        {{#each posts}}
            {{> postItem}}
        {{/each}}

    </div>
</template>
```

and

```
<template name="postItem">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-content">
            <h3><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a><span>{{domain}}</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and the js:

```
Template.postsList.helpers({
    posts: function() {
        return Posts.find();
    }
});
```

and

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
    domain: function() {
        var a = document. createElement('a');
        a.href = this.url;
        return a.hostname;
    }
});
```

After this, I am just getting nothing displayed and the HTML is

```
<div class="posts"></div>
```

I have some records in my database:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.posts.find();
{ "_id" : "6ZCDcmn5iP3RSMLdk", "title" : "I
cha Greif", "url" : "http://sachagreif.com/
{ "_id" : "TKEsA83TgTtSmG4Ev", "title" : "M
l" : "http://meteor.com" }
{ "_id" : "R9dacSb3Lw8zuHqzq", "title" : "T
man", "url" : "http://themeteorbook.com" }
```

What am I missing????

Comment: Is that space before `createElement` a typo?

Comment: Also, when you type `meteor list`, do you still have the `autopublish` package installed? If not, you will need to add subscriptions and publications. But I'm guessing you are not that far in the tutorial so it should still be activated...

Comment: Of course!  Thank you.  I had renamed a file that contained the subscription stuff. (main.js for those with a similar problem).  Thank you very much.